# The JSON output does not contain a key: "value"

Tags: json, swift, parsing, nsdictionary

I have a `JSON` parsing issue with my Swift code below. The error I am getting says that my `JSON` output does not contain a key `value`.

**My code:**

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

     let jsonValue = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
     if let bpArray = jsonValue["value"] as? [NSDictionary]{
         for  results in bpArray {...}
```

**Issue:**
This conversion doesnt work: `if let bpArray = jsonValue["value"] as? [NSDictionary]`

**My JSON Structure:**

```
{
    d: {
        results: [
            {
                __metadata: {},
                Key: "AFBWhULFHtKU4j4FhWCmKg==",
                ParentKey: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==",
                RootKey: "AFBWhULFHtKU4j4FhWCmKg==",
                Partner: "MM-CARR-01",
                Type: "2",
                Description: "MM Demo Carrier Created for Single Stop / MA",
                FrieghtOrder: {}
            },
        ...
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Errors, `nil` values, etc.

Comment: The JSON output does not contain a key `value`

Comment: Looking at your `JSON` object, it looks like it, in fact, does not have any properties named "value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to access the results key so try like this:-

```
if let bpArray = jsonValue["results"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
//yourcode
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this idea did the magic. Yes like most people said "Value" doesnt exist, I didnt use results directly I had to navigate from d->results as shown below:                
                if let bpData = jsonValue["d"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    
                    for results  in bpData {
            
                        let arrayInterim = results.value as? NSArray
    
                        for i in 0 ..< arrayInterim!.count {

Comment: If you think it helps then please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Well your json structure haven't got any key named as value and that's why it's giving an error.
In order to get results array, you first need to get the object in which they are nested and for example `'g'` in your case:

```
if let data = jsonValue["d"] as? [NSDictionary]{
     if let resultsArray = data["results"] as? NSArray {
         //your code
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Swifty Json Pod And Try this code

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

In Your file where you get response

```
import  SwiftyJSON
```

Then After Use This Code

```
         switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON2):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON2)")
              //  print("Request failed with error: \(response.response?.statusCode)")

                if let response = JSON2 as? NSMutableDictionary
                {

                }
                else if let response = JSON2 as? NSDictionary
                {
 if let data = response?.object(forKey: "d") as? NSDictionary
 {
    if let resultsArray = data?.object(forKey: "results") as? NSArray 
        {

         }
 }
                }
                else if JSON2 is NSArray
                {

                    let swjson = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    print(swjson)
                    // callback(swjson,nil)
                    var myMutableDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()
                    myMutableDictionary["myArray"] = swjson

                    callback(myMutableDictionary as NSDictionary?,nil)
                    print("accc")
                }
                else if ((JSON2 as? String) != nil)
                {

                    let userDic : [String : String] = ["quatid":JSON2 as! String]
                    print(userDic)


            }

                break

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember it's better we not use `NSArray` & `NSDictionary` like things in `SWIFT`, `SWIFT` it self providing `let`, `var` keyword for various data type.
First you can create your model where you can save the data.

**MyModel.swift**

```
class MyModel: NSObject {
    var ParentKey : Int?

    init(jsonObject:[String:Any]) {
        ParentKey = jsonObject["ParentKey"] as? String ?? ""
  }
}
```

**Viewcontroller.Swift**

```
    var myModel : [MyModel] = []
    if let responseData = response["d"] as? [String:Any]{
              if let dataObject = responseData["results"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                 self.myModel = dataObject.map({return MyModel(jsonObject: $0)})//for assigning data into model
                }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

As most people said, I was wrong with "value". Hussain's answer to using `[String:AnyObject]` Helped.

I am not sure if the below is neat to achieve, but it did the magic. App loaded as expected. Code expert below:

**Solution:**

```
        if let bpData = jsonValue["d"] as? [String: AnyObject]{

            for results  in bpData {

                let arrayInterim = results.value as? NSArray

                for i in 0 ..< arrayInterim!.count {
```